# Python Remove Whitespace

Tags: python, file

This is **my first question** so forgive me if this is not a well formed question but I am trying to read the contents of a file in Python.

So far I could print the contents of the file but there are whitespaces at the beginning and end of each line and I don't want the whitespaces on the **beginning**. How do I do that.

```
with open('dump.txt','r') as f:
    print f.read()
```

Thanks!

Comment: `map(str.lstrip, f.readlines())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
with open('dump.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.lstrip()
```

`lstrip` specifically removes the whitespace from the beginning of the string.

**PS.** `read` gives you the whole content of the file, you better operate on the line level by `readline`

**UPDATE:**
As pointed out, there are severals ways of doing this and one other way is to read the contents of the file via `readlines` and iterate through that list to strip the whitespace.

Comment: If you don't want your answer to become a duplicate of hiro protagonist's, you _could_ show how to do this task using the file `.readlines()` method.

Answer (score 1):

this reads the file line for line and left-strips each line

```
with open('dump.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print line.lstrip()
```

Answer (score 1):

To cut off trailing or leading white spaces you can do

```
>>'  Test  '.lstrip()
'Test  '
```

or

```
>>'Test  '.rstrip()
'Test  '
```

or

```
>>'Test  '.strip()
'Test'
```